# Сайт на Joomla перенести в мобильную версию (PDA)

Tags: joomla

Всех с наступающим Новым Годом! Прошу у вас ответа на данный вопрос: как "протестить" версию сайта для КПК на ПК. Скачал Opera Mobile Emulator - не могу вникнуть :) Сайт на Joomla. Тестируется в локальной сети (Denwer). Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Есть отличный сайт http://www.browserstack.com/ . Правда там даётся всего 30 минут бесплатных, но т.к. подтверждение по почте не требуется - то можно каждый раз генерировать новый аккаунт с левой почтой и использовать его.

Правда для этого придётся "открыть Denwer наружу". Соответственно адресом сайта будет твой IP либо можно использовать сервис no-ip.org.

Comment: Спасибо. P.S. Мой вопрос-это не проблема. Сайт 3-4 января будет уже на сервере компании-хостинга. Можно в 01:00 временно отключить на "техобслуживание" - и тестировать. Но хочется клиенту предварительно показать.

Comment: Открываешь "Денвер" наружу и показываешь клиенту, либо смотришь сам. Т.к. IP или домен (имя.no-ip.org) будешь знать только ты и те, кому их скажешь - то сайт будут видеть только те, кто знают их.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз. И с Наступающим Новым Годом!